# media:content tag missing from Joomla RSS Feed

Tags: joomla-4, content, rss

I am using mailchimp to send newsletters. Everything works fine apart from the fact that my RSS feed generated by Joomla does not contain the media:content tag, hence mailchimp doesn't show the images corellated to the articles. **My website is based on Joomla 4.**

The (hidden) menu through which the RSS feed is generated (the menu contains the latest articles, about 10 of them on each page of the menu) is a SP Builder Page, so I studied its structure and located the div inside where the article links/images/title etc. are.

I wrote this simple JS script which outputs the 7 first image links from the blog feed:

```
var imageDivs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".article-intro-image"));

for (let i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    console.log (imageDivs[i].firstElementChild.currentSrc.replace("thumbnail", "large").replace("small", "large"));
}
```

How do I go about integrating this to the Joomla core "Syndicate RSS feed" module? Is there, perhaps, an easier way instead of custom code and overrides? I have not been able to find an extension in the Joomla community that solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks for joining us Anton.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.